# js onmouseover change css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a "link" or menu with mouse hover.
So when you hover the mouse on the css / menu should changes to a "class" active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with pure JavaScript or jQuery

JQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="myLink"></a>

$(".myLink").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}, 

// mouse out
function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i],
    classes = link.getAttribute("class");

    if (classes.indexOf("myLink") > -1) {
        link.onmouseover = function() {
            this.setAttribute("class", classes + " active");
        }
        // Remove active class
        link.onmouseout = function() {
            this.setAttribute("class", classes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I resolved my question.

Answer (score 1):

CSS and HTML :

```css
li
{
  display : inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background : blue;
}

li:hover
{
  background : #4286f4;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none;color:white;" >
<li>
 item1
</li>
<li>
  item2
</li>
<li>
  item2
</li>
</ul>
```

I used hover selector of CSS, this changes background when user hovers over the `li` element .
I used `inline-block` so that all li elements are displayed side by side

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your active class is just add selector `a:hover` before the active class

```
a:hover, active{
    color:red;
 }
```

Now, whenever you hover the link it will have the effect of active class.

```css
a:hover, active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Link</a>
```

**Update**

If you want to add a class on hover of the link you can do this way, in pure javascript

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(link){
    link.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
        this.classList.add('active');
    })
});
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```